# Using a form control as a field selector in SQL query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am attempting to build a form ,called UI, that users will select a dimension parameter from a combobox "cmbFilter" and then add a +/- tolerance in a text box "txtTolerance". After selection a part number from a list this should return results for similar part numbers in the the tolorence range for that parameter.  The field names in the table are the dimension parameters and are `.AddItem` to the combobox in the form load code.

Example. Part#1 OD is 5, so I select "OD" as the search parameter then I set a tolerance to +/- 1. The results should show Part#2 with a OD of 6 but not Part#3 with a OD of 7.

[image]

I have set a listboxs row source to the query but
no matter what I change in the syntax in this code I get operation or syntax errors. So I assume Im not referencing the form control right, or my logic isn't right?

I have tired the following code in the SQL design view in access.

SQL

```
  SELECT Part_Matrix.Part_Number, Part_Matrix.Customer, Part_Matrix.Large_OD, Part_Matrix.Vent_Opening, & _
  Part_Matrix.BPT, Part_Matrix.MFT, Part_Matrix.PD, Part_Matrix.Hat_ID, Part_Matrix.Microfinish, & _
  Part_Matrix.Turn_Operations, Part_Matrix.Stud_Holes, Part_Matrix.SH_Dimensions, Part_Matrix.Manufacturer_Holes, & _
  Part_Matrix.MH_Dimensions, Part_Matrix.Other_Holes, Part_Matrix.Other_Dimension
  FROM Part_Matrix
  WHERE [Forms]![UI]![cmbFilter]
  BETWEEN (((SELECT  [Forms]![UI]![cmbFilter] FROM Part_Matrix WHERE Part_Number = [Forms]![UI]![lbSelected])   - [Forms]![UI]![txtTolerance])
  AND ((SELECT  [Forms]![UI]![cmbFilter] FROM Part_Matrix WHERE Part_Number = [Forms]![UI]![lbSelected])   + [Forms]![UI]![txtTolerance]))
 ORDER BY [Forms]![UI]![cmbFilter] DESC;
```

I have also tried to write the SQL code in access vba still no luck, the code below was just a simple text, I know its now the same logic as above.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
Dim SQL As String
If txtTolerance = "" Then
    MsgBox ("No Tolerance Entered")
    Exit Sub
ElseIf cmbFilter = "" Then
    MsgBox ("No Filter Criteria Entered")
    Exit Sub
Else

    SQL = "SELECT Part_Matrix.[Part_Number], " & Me.cmbFilter & " " & _
    "FROM Part_Matrix" & _
    "ORDER BY " & Me.cmbFilter & " DESC;"

    Debug.Print SQL
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
    lbFilterResults.RowSource = SQL
    lbFilterResults.Requery
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `...FROM Part_MatrixORDER BY...` you need to leave spaces between the words in your query.

Comment: are you talking about in the vba? or the query?

Comment: Your SQL variable's value in your VBA: you haven't left a space between Part_Matrix and ORDER

Comment: @TimWilliams @geeFlo Ok I think im getting alittle to detailed. I Simply want the following to work if you can help me `SELECT *Selected Field From Combobox Here* FROM Part_Matrix` With that the SQL returns the literal field name from the combobox 178 times, 1 for each record. Its not selecting the values from records from that specific field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, using a dlookup instead of SELECT to return the values you want in the BETWEEN statement.  I believe the dlookup should return the value for whatever field you select in the combo box.  Also, I've simplified to remove the forms!UI statement with a "me" assuming you are running code from the same form.  Let me know if this works for ya.

```
intTarget = dlookup(me!CmbFilter, "PartMatrix", "Part_Number = " & me!LbSelected)
intLower = intTarget - me!txtTolerance
intUpper = intTarget + me!txtTolerance

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Part_Matrix WHERE " & me!cmbFilter & " " & _
          "BETWEEN " & intLower & " AND " & intUpper
```

Comment: I like where this going but I get an error, `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Part_Number] = 01.N221.10`  01.N221.10 is the lbSelected

Comment: Ahh got it, `intTarget = DLookup(Forms![UI]!cmbFilter, "Part_Matrix", "Part_Matrix.Part_Number = '" & Me!lbSelected.Value & "'")`. You missed the `&"'"` at the end and the `'` at the beginning. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah yes the dreaded string vs numeric ID.   Glad it worked out for ya.

Answer (score 0):

In your BETWEEN statement, reference the table's [Large_OD] field and not the form'S.

i.e

```
 WHERE Large_OD
  BETWEEN (((SELECT  Large_OD FROM Part_Matrix WHERE Part_Number = [Forms]![UI]![lbSelected])   - [Forms]![UI]![txtTolerance])
  AND ((SELECT  Large_OD FROM Part_Matrix WHERE Part_Number = [Forms]![UI]![lbSelected])   + [Forms]![UI]![txtTolerance]))
 ORDER BY " & Me.cmbFilter & " DESC;
```

Comment: thanks techspider.  new to this and didn't know how to block the code like that.

Comment: The user changes the search parameter, its not always Large_OD. The point is that what ever field name is selected in the combo box is the search parameter, `WHERE "Selected Search Parameter"`. The example I gave was Large_OD. It could be Small_OD , BPT , theres 13 different options.

Comment: I think I get it now.  See my other answer that I just posted.